# Can't commit animation on 2 UIView

Tags: animation, uiview

I'm trying to move 2 views together :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                        [currentView setCenter:CGPointMake(currentView.center.x + currentView.frame.size.width, currentView.center.y)];
                        [nextView setCenter:CGPointMake(nextView.center.x + nextView.frame.size.width, nextView.center.y)];
}];
```

However, I can't manage to do it. Only the nextView is moving.

If I just commit the animation on just one, it works fine.

What could be the reason?
Could it be because of my declaration :

```
nextView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:currentView.frame];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correct you have 2 views with the exact same frame, being animated in the exact same way.  Could it be that they are both moving but one is on top of the other so you only see the top view?

Comment: They have the same frame for initialization, but after, "nextView" is set at the left of the screen, so it would display a "pushing" effect

Comment: if that is the case then the code you have posted is fine and the error is somewhere else.  Could you post more code?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my problem.

The main difference between my two view is that one is created from a .xib, the other programmatically. 
And everything work by writing :

```
[currentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
```

So is there something to change in the .xib file, so I would not have to set this mask programmatically.